# 'Uniformization'?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, uniform-distribution

I am looking for a better term for what I call '*uniformification*', where I change data to make it more close to uniformly distributed.

I am doing a project in which I try to make the output of a neural network uniformly distributed over the output space. Let's call the neural network $f(x | \theta)$, where $\theta$ contains the weights and other tunable parameters. What I do is to change the parameters of the network $\theta$ such that the output is closer to a uniform distribution. You could say I am making the output more uniform by modifying the function $f(x|\theta)$.

How would I call this process?

I was thinking of the term '***uniformification***', but it sounds kind of weird. What could be a better term for this? Or is there already a term for this in the literature?

**PS**: in no case will I use a transformation on either $x$, $\theta$ or on the output $f(x|\theta)$ in order to make the output more uniform. I am only adjusting the weights $\theta$ in order to achieve that.

**Edit**: According to [this post on the suffixes -ise, -ate and -ify](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26751/suffixes-for-verbification-ify-icise-ificate), the term should actually be '**uniformization**'.

Comment: you might find the [probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) relevant.

Comment: @TooTone : thanks, but not really. My transformation is an artificial neural network.

Comment: Just to flag that I have no idea how using an artificial neural network works here. If you are using a standard procedure, there may be a name in the literature, but I wouldn't know about it. Consider adding different tags if you want to get more attention from machine learning people.

Comment: I've added the tag machine-learning. I am not using a standard procedure, but the name of the concept which I call 'uniformification' should be irrespective of what method I use to achieve it.

Comment: "should" is a difficult word. It's much more common in my experience that the same idea gets different names in different fields.

Comment: By *definition* the transformation that makes a distribution uniform is the probability integral transform!

Comment: @whuber : I am not looking for such a transformation. I am looking for the term for a *change* of the transformation I already have. Note that my transformation may have a different number of output variables than input variables, which is not the case for a probability integral transform. By that reasoning I would say your statement is false.

Comment: Thank you: that makes it even more apparent that there is some miscommunication going on.  Please read over the answers and comments and use their suggestions to edit your question.

Comment: @whuber, I hope now my question is more clear.

Comment: Even with the edits (thank you) I still understand your question in the sense that @Nick Cox answered it, but you do not seem to have modified your objections to his answer, nor have your edits indicated any way in which his answer ought to change.

Comment: What's wrong with my objections to his answer?

Comment: @whuber I know that it's hard to change your interpretation once you are settled on one. I hope that by introducing mathematical notation it is now clear that changing a transformation $f(x | \theta)$ by changing $\theta$ doesn't constitute the composition of $f$ with another function $g$, which is how I think you interpret it.

Comment: If it's still not clear I will delete the whole question and start a new post and formulate everything anew. The question I am asking shouldn't be so difficult to interpret. Maybe I just used the wrong words.

Comment: It's not in the least difficult to interpret.  What is puzzling is that others have apparently understood the question, have provided good answers and comments, an answer is being upvoted, but yet you appear to believe it does not answer your question.

Comment: His answer is basically saying "You should call the change of a transformation such that the output is more uniform a 'transformation'. Furthermore, changing a transformation is the same as composing two transformations." The first part of this is similar to saying "You should call the kind of cutlery with which you cut cutlery, instead of a knife." The second part I have clearly disproven by my last comment. I dont think people have provided good answers. Please support this claim with reasoning.

Comment: In statistics a transformation can exist in a family, for example, the Box-Cox family tuned by a power.

Comment: "Users can delete their own questions if the question: has zero answers, or only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes." So, sorry you haven't been answered to your satisfaction, but you don't have scope to delete this. I don't think you have a disproof, but different terminology.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you would call changing $\theta$ in order to change the transformation $f(x|\theta)$ a function composition? Is that the difference in terminology?

Comment: Darn, I can't delete my own post. Oh dear. What I can do, though, is change the question such that your answer is the answer to the correct question. ;)

Comment: You have the scope to edit your own question. Note that I then have scope to edit my answer. Let's leave this as unresolved to your satisfaction but as of possible interest to others. However, I have tweaked my answer in a way that may come a little closer to your notions.

Comment: Of course I will not edit my question in such a way until we have figures out whether or not you did indeed misunderstand my question, or I misunderstood your answer. (It was more of a joke.) But you still haven't answered the question 2 comments above, which I think is quite crucial to my understanding of your answer. Would you call changing $\theta$ in order to change $f(x|\theta)$ a transformation which is composed onto the transformation $f$ itself? That is the only way in which I think this conflict is caused by misunderstanding of terminology.

Comment: Maybe my latest edit will bring some light.

Comment: I did address that question by removing the implication that combination (undefined) implies composite. But what is, or is not, composite seems quite secondary to your main question. Transformations that depend on (vary with) parameters are utterly standard, as I underlined earlier.

Comment: Maybe you did address the question in some way, but to me it is still not clear what your answer would be. Yer or no? What are you proving by saying that transformations usually depend on parameters?

Comment: I am not attempting proof or disproof; I am not attempting to answer your question in your style. I am commenting on terminology as used in statistical science. I would not spontaneously call changing a parameter in a transformation composition of transformations, but tuning a parameter is entirely consistent with the idea of transformations.

Answer (score 5):

It's a transformation. By analogy with other procedures, you might call it transformation to uniform scores. "Uniformification" is certainly an ugly word and I strongly recommend against it.

But the best name depends at least partly on how you do it.

In particular, the transformation to ranks, with averaging for ties, achieves a uniform distribution, except in so far as there are spikes and gaps as a side-effect of the ties. Unless you violate a principle that identical values mean identical transformed values, it is difficult to see how you could make a distribution more nearly uniform.

Naturally, scaling ranks to fit in $[0, 1]$ or any other interval is just cosmetic or a matter of convenience.

UPDATE (updated) The idea, and the terminology, of transformations within statistics are completely compatible with the ideas that transformations can be applied in sequence; that a given transformation can be a composite of others; and that a transformation can be a family, i.e. tuned by one or more parameters. An example of moderate historical importance is the so-called angular transformation, which is arcsine of square root of proportions. (Note that in this case, the proportions could, and indeed usually would, be transformations of some original data.) I say *within statistics* but I would assert that this idea and terminology are consistent with mathematics generally. In sum, what you are doing is a sequence of transformations; the target is a uniform distribution; it doesn't need a special or novel name, and none obviously exists at present.

Comment: I am not looking for a particular transformation which makes the output distribution uniform. I am looking at changing a given transformation (a neural network) such that its output pdf is more transform. The concept of 'uniformification' applies irrespective of what kind of transformation I actually use, as long as the transformation can be (gradually) modified.

Comment: "more transform"?? If you mean more nearly uniform, I think most statistical people would call that a transformation. My answer imputed a general statistical orientation given the vagueness of your original question. If you want more attention from machine learning (neural network) users, please edit  the content or tags of your question. Sorry, no idea on what the last sentence means. Again, more detail would help.

Comment: It's the reference to gradual modification that isn't obvious (to me).

Comment: My question is not vague, but abstract. People often confuse those two. And yes, that was a typo. I meant "uniform". Calling it a transformation is uninformative, since the thing I am trying to name is the transformation of a transformation, toward a transformation which makes the data uniform. I am *changing* the transformation of the data in a way that the output of that transformation is more uniform than the output was before that change.

Comment: By "vague" I meant vague about what you are doing; I think the word was fair. More importantly, you are asking about what language people use, and the top term is transformation, as used by everyone contributing answers or comments so far. I am now completely lost on what you are doing, and I strongly recommend that you make this completely concrete, not more and more abstract. Alternatively, this is a hidden mathematics question.

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: By transforming a transformation I am not composing transformations, but changing a transformation into another transformation. If I change $f^0(x) = \text{fibbonacci}(x)$ into $f^1(x) = x^2$ I am not composing $f^0$ with $f^1$ or with any other function.

Comment: In that sense we can gradually change $f(x | \theta)$ by gradually changing $\theta$.

Comment: Sorry, but I agree with the others here, Angelorf. Your problem was interpreted correctly and answered. You seem not to want to accept that answer. And are veering off into other topics that indicate you don't quite understand what it is that you're actually doing with these transformation operations. If the objective of your project is to examine the distribution of the output of a neural network, under no circumstances are you allowed to *change* your output to conform to a uniform distribution. You can't change output data just because you think it should conform to a whatever distribution.

Comment: @rocinante everybody seems to interpret what I said as though I want to change the output by applying a transformation afterwards. I cannot seem to shake this idea in your minds. I am only changing the output by changing *the network itself*. Exactly *that* is the objective of my project! I aim for a neural network which has outputs which follow a uniform distribution. I will thus update my weights accordingly. The only transformation taking place is the neural network itself!

Comment: Let's reverse your argument: if you don't like the advice here (and the implicit stance that terminology from mainstream statistics can be used or borrowed), no offence taken, and I see two other possibilities for you. 1. You invent your own terminology because no terminology you know of appears appropriate to you (no sarcasm or irony; that's how all terminology starts). 2. You spell out what you are doing in a new question with much more detail and seek advice specifically from machine learning people or more generally anyone versed in neural nets.

Comment: @Angelorf it doesn't matter where the transformation happens, be it in the network itself or afterwards. The transformation that is being done is known as the probability integral transform. As such, you can describe your model as "yields the probability integral transform of blahblah" where blahblah is the rest your NN does.

Comment: @MarcClaesen it certainly does matter if the *output* data is being transformed. The objective of analysis is usually to analyze the output that results from the given system. You can't change output just because you don't like what you have. That's why there are rules about what transformations you can apply. If you want to change the system to give you a certain output, then that's something different and not really a stats problem.

Comment: @rocinante that does not influence the proper name of what's going on, though. Whether or not doing this is a good idea is a different matter entirely. I agree with you that the concept sounds suspicious, but more context is required to assess that.

Comment: @MarcClaesen there is no transformation other than the network itself! There is no transformation *in* the network. It is only the network itself which can be viewed as a transformation. And we cannot reduce neural networks to the probability integral transform!

Comment: @Angelorf if you use a neural network to model a continuous output, the model is said to do regression, if you use it to model discrete outputs the model is said to be classification. Mutatis mutandis, if you use the model to "uniformicate" your data, it can be said that the model is a surrogate probability integral transform. If it quacks, you may as well call it a duck.

Comment: @MarcClaesen Well that's kind of true, but a probability integral distribution always has the same number of outputs as inputs, in contrast to neural networks. Moreover, the probability integral transform is not the only transformation which causes uniform output, so even though my neural network would make the output uniform, doesn't mean that input points are mapped to the same location in output space.